# Multiple Vertical Axes with addtional label - Teechart

Tags: axis, teechart

recently I met a problem about Teechart Programming. I got a software which was written in C++ Builder with Teechart 8, below is a screenshot. And that's all I know about the  software. I was curious about how to realize that with teechart.

I walked through the offcial tutorial and by new a TChartAxis I can divide the chart into n pieces.

What make me so puzzled is how to add addtional labels(aligned-left) and how to set their color, font and size in code.

I'm sorry for my poor English and you will make my day, I'm looking forward to your point.

Best wishes~ :)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create an axis in a chart, it needs a series with data linked to it. Then, both the axis, grids, labels and the series will be drawn.
Find an example (and its code) of the custom axes usage at "All features\Welcome !\Axes\Opaque zones" in the "TeeChart compiled demo"
[here](http://www.steema.com/download/vcl).

Comment: Thanks Yeray, I'm downlading the Demo. What made me puzzled is the addtional labels aligned the left of every "subchart" of the chart.

Comment: If after looking at the demo (and worth to mention the tutorials too) you still find problems with it, don't hesitate to let us know.

Comment: Hi Yeray, I got the tutorial, my problem is how to divide the chart into N vertical-continuous-pieces which share the same bottom axis like the image listed above.http://i.stack.imgur.com/pYrP6.png

Comment: In that "Opaque zones" example, 4 vertical axes are used to divide the chart in 4 zones (3 custom axes and the default left axis). To divide it in N parts, just create N vertical custom axes (or N-1 custom axes and the default left axis) and use the axes StartPosition and EndPosition properties to place them accordingly.